# Can you cycle through multiple plots in a single figure window in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I am trying to figure how one can plot multiple plots in a single figure, but ***NOT*** using a subplot and ***NOT*** on the same axes. Essentially, what I would like to do is, for example, have separate plots of `sine`, `cosine`, and `tangent`. They would all be in the same figure window, and you can use the arrow key to change between to the different plots. I'm imagining it requires having them stored in a list or array.

If this has been asked somewhere else on here, kindly point me in that direction, and I'll close this question.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can have a look at widgets such as [menu](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.1/examples/widgets/menu.html) and [button](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.1/examples/widgets/buttons.html). Personally, I think that  [bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) works better than matplotlib when it comes to interactive plots.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments section, you may use **bokeh**. Completely inspired from the [bokeh documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#tab-panes), an implementation could be the following:

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs
from numpy import pi, arange, sin, cos
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, figure, show

output_file("slider.html")

x = arange(-2*pi, 2*pi, 0.1)
# your different functions
y1 = sin(x)
y2 = cos(x)

# building a tab per function/plot
p1 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p1.circle(x, y1, color="red")
tab1 = Panel(child=p1, title="sinus")

p2 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p2.circle(x, y2, color="blue")
tab2 = Panel(child=p2, title="cosinus")

# aggregating and plotting
tabs = Tabs(tabs=[tab1, tab2])
show(tabs)
```